# Is there a name indicating the following graph?

Tags: mathematics

I know that the following graph is called a "Histogram".
[image: hist]

---

On the other hand, what ist the name of the following graph?

[image: graph]

I think this is one of the most common graphs, but I do not know this graph's name. (I always just called it a "graph".)

---

Actually, I drew two graphs for my data set.
One is drawn in the histogram fashion, and the other is in the below way.
I want to explain the graphs well, but I cannot know how to say the below graph.

Please let me know the below graph's name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in the type of "Line Graph", but to be specific it should be called "Timeplot".

Reference: http://www.statisticshowto.com/line-graph/